# iOS app termination due to uncaught error

Tags: ios

This is the exception and in my ignorance of using the tools in the IDE I have a very basic question. How do I go to the line of code that causes the issue? I have located where the issue is, but rather than NSLogging a message in the `didload` and `didAppear` events, then stepping through the code until is breaks seems like a long way to figure this out. I am assuming that the [5970:1623718] is a clue, but to what?

```
2017-10-04 08:22:47.798 Auto Mileage - Universal[5970:1623718] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 4 beyond bounds [0 .. 3]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2580f91b 0x24faae17 0x2572172b 0xd89e3 0xd9e57 0x2a0d1465 0x2a0d15a5 0x2a0c0b51 0x2a0d5d1b 0x29e7523b 0x29d86a73 0x27e1ebcd 0x27e1a375 0x27e1a209 0x27e196d1 0x27e193a5 0x29d7db79 0x257d16c9 0x257cf9cd 0x257cfdff 0x2571f229 0x2571f015 0x26d0fac9 0x29df3189 0xe9159 0x253c7873)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: You should add an [exception breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802662/exception-breakpoint-in-xcode).

Answer (score 0):

You can add an "Exception Breakpoint".

[image]

Like in the picture, select "Show the Breakpoint navigator" (the blue icon on the top of the navigator), then click on the plus icon on the bottom and click on "Add Exception Breakpoint".